# Generate multiple square from points cloud

Tags: c++, square

I have a set of points and I want to have all possible square possible from it.
How can I do to achieve it (which methods?).

I have proceeded as followed I iterate the points array successively and it does not give all possible square. I create One main loop where inside I have One second loop to get in each iteration give me 3 points

Best regards

Comment: Having a trivial case (2D axis aligned): Use two scan lines (one in x the other y-direction)  and iterate from (xmin, ymin) to (xmax,ymax). If both scan lines include more than one point try to construct a square. (This is just a sketch)

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: Take a pencil and  paper, to sketch it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there is something more efficient, but my suggestion would be to start by calculation the distances between each pair of points:

```
distance[N][N];
distance[i][j] = distance between point i and point j
```

Next you search for points `j` and `k` that have the same distance from a given point `i`. We also have to check that the angle is 90°. And the you still have to find the fourth point..

```
for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
    for (int j=i+1;j<N;j++){
        for (int k=j+1;k<N;k++){
            if (abs(distances[i][j] - distances[i][k]) < eps){
                if (abs(distances[j][k] - sqrt(2)*distances[i][j]) < eps){
                    ... find a point with same distance from k and j....
                }
            }
        }
    }     
}
```

...well, while writing I realized that this might be complete overkill (too many loops..) but it might be a starting point. 
    }